# Is there a shorter way to remove line breaks when reading from a file to a list?

Tags: python, list, file-io, whitespace, strip

Here is my current code:

```
dfile = open('dictionary.txt', 'r')
sfile = open('substrings.txt', 'r')
dictionary_words = []
substrings = []

for line in dfile:
    dictionary_words.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
for line in sfile:
    substrings.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
```

It works but seems pretty wordy.

Is this the appropriate way to write this out, or am I missing a simpler process?

Comment: Well you're doing the exact same thing twice in a row. If nothing else, you could at least refactor it into a function or method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open('dictionary.txt', 'r') as f:
    dictionary_words = f.read().splitlines()
```

Answer (score 4):

Either use [`map`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map):

```
dictionary_words = map(lambda line: line.rstrip('\n'), dfile)
```

or a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
dictionary_words = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in dfile]
```

Answer (score 3):

A slightly less wordy alternative is to use list comprehensions:

```
with open('dictionary.txt', 'r') as dfile:
  dictionary_words = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in dfile]

with open('substrings.txt', 'r') as sfile:
  substrings  = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in sfile]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems your dictionary file has one word at line. It may help you:

```
>>> words = [w.strip() for w in open('dictionary.txt').read().split('\n')]
```

Comment: split('\n') leaves an empty string after the last line.  splitlines() avoids it.

Answer (score 1):

As @Chris mentions in the comment you could define a function:

```
def words_fromfile(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
         return f.read().splitlines()

dictionary_words = words_fromfile('dictionary.txt')
substrings = words_fromfile('substrings.txt')
```

You could always change the function definition later if you don't like it for some reason without touching the rest of the code.